# how to search through the array and return the matching value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scope, return

I have an array of some class names that all of the values in that array end with numbers. I want to have a function that when I give it a number, it search through that array, and check the last 3 digits of each value, to find the matching number and return that matching value.
So lets say, I give it value `200` and it searches through the array and returns `wi-owm-200`.

I manage to make it but it does not return it. It does find the value, but when it is outside of the function, it returns 'undefined'.

Here is my code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zse03833/)

```js
var owmIcon = ["wi-owm-200", "wi-owm-201", "wi-owm-202", "wi-owm-210", "wi-owm-211", "wi-owm-212", "wi-owm-221", "wi-owm-230", "wi-owm-231", "wi-owm-232", "wi-owm-300", "wi-owm-301", "wi-owm-302", "wi-owm-310", "wi-owm-311", "wi-owm-312", "wi-owm-313", "wi-owm-314", "wi-owm-321", "wi-owm-500", "wi-owm-501", "wi-owm-502", "wi-owm-503", "wi-owm-504", "wi-owm-511", "wi-owm-520", "wi-owm-521", "wi-owm-522", "wi-owm-531", "wi-owm-600", "wi-owm-601", "wi-owm-602", "wi-owm-611", "wi-owm-612", "wi-owm-615", "wi-owm-616", "wi-owm-620", "wi-owm-621", "wi-owm-622", "wi-owm-701", "wi-owm-711", "wi-owm-721", "wi-owm-731", "wi-owm-741", "wi-owm-761", "wi-owm-762", "wi-owm-771", "wi-owm-781", "wi-owm-800", "wi-owm-801", "wi-owm-802", "wi-owm-803", "wi-owm-804", "wi-owm-900", "wi-owm-901", "wi-owm-902", "wi-owm-903", "wi-owm-904", "wi-owm-905", "wi-owm-906", "wi-owm-957"];


var res = findOWMIcon("200");
console.log(res);


function findOWMIcon(num) {
  $.each(owmIcon, function(key, value) {
    var classNum = value.substr(value.length - 3);
    if (parseInt(num, 10) === parseInt(classNum, 10)) {
      console.log(value);
      return value;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea how to solve it? So I can get the found value outside the function?

Comment: Why would it return `word-200`? There isn't an element called that in the array.

Comment: @Andy no `word-200` was and example only. In fact it has to return something like `wi-owm-200`. gonna update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sufficient:

```
owmIcon.filter(e => e.slice(-3) == "200");
```

```js
// Get all elements that ends in "01"
items = get_all_items().filter(e => e.slice(-2) == "01");
console.log(items);

function get_all_items(){
  return ["wi-owm-200", "wi-owm-201", "wi-owm-202", "wi-owm-210", "wi-owm-211", "wi-owm-212", "wi-owm-221", "wi-owm-230", "wi-owm-231", "wi-owm-232", "wi-owm-300", "wi-owm-301", "wi-owm-302", "wi-owm-310", "wi-owm-311", "wi-owm-312", "wi-owm-313", "wi-owm-314", "wi-owm-321", "wi-owm-500", "wi-owm-501", "wi-owm-502", "wi-owm-503", "wi-owm-504", "wi-owm-511", "wi-owm-520", "wi-owm-521", "wi-owm-522", "wi-owm-531", "wi-owm-600", "wi-owm-601", "wi-owm-602", "wi-owm-611", "wi-owm-612", "wi-owm-615", "wi-owm-616", "wi-owm-620", "wi-owm-621", "wi-owm-622", "wi-owm-701", "wi-owm-711", "wi-owm-721", "wi-owm-731", "wi-owm-741", "wi-owm-761", "wi-owm-762", "wi-owm-771", "wi-owm-781", "wi-owm-800", "wi-owm-801", "wi-owm-802", "wi-owm-803", "wi-owm-804", "wi-owm-900", "wi-owm-901", "wi-owm-902", "wi-owm-903", "wi-owm-904", "wi-owm-905", "wi-owm-906", "wi-owm-957"];
}
```

Use `function(e){ return e.slice(-3) == "200"; }` instead of `e => ...` if you care about backward compatibility (ES5 and before).

Comment: will match 1200 or 2200 also

Comment: @charlietfl And that is true, as described in the question: "*it search through that array, check the last 3 digits of each value.*"

Comment: missed that...just saw series getting up in 900's

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the answer, It does the job. However, is there any way to avoid `=>` ?! as you know it is ES6 and IE does not support it. I need a solution that is working in all browsers including "rare IE users".

Comment: @DannyBoy Read the answer carefully again, especially the last sentence.

Comment: @DannyBoy By the way, you can start using ES6+ code by transpiling it to ES5 using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the last part. Great code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = ["wi-owm-200", "wi-owm-201", "wi-owm-202", "wi-owm-210", "wi-owm-211", "wi-owm-212", "wi-owm-221", "wi-owm-230", "wi-owm-231", "wi-owm-232", "wi-owm-300", "wi-owm-301", "wi-owm-302", "wi-owm-310", "wi-owm-311", "wi-owm-312", "wi-owm-313", "wi-owm-314", "wi-owm-321", "wi-owm-500", "wi-owm-501", "wi-owm-502", "wi-owm-503", "wi-owm-504", "wi-owm-511", "wi-owm-520", "wi-owm-521", "wi-owm-522", "wi-owm-531", "wi-owm-600", "wi-owm-601", "wi-owm-602", "wi-owm-611", "wi-owm-612", "wi-owm-615", "wi-owm-616", "wi-owm-620", "wi-owm-621", "wi-owm-622", "wi-owm-701", "wi-owm-711", "wi-owm-721", "wi-owm-731", "wi-owm-741", "wi-owm-761", "wi-owm-762", "wi-owm-771", "wi-owm-781", "wi-owm-800", "wi-owm-801", "wi-owm-802", "wi-owm-803", "wi-owm-804", "wi-owm-900", "wi-owm-901", "wi-owm-902", "wi-owm-903", "wi-owm-904", "wi-owm-905", "wi-owm-906", "wi-owm-957"];

// Suppose you want to get all elements that end with 200, so...

let filteredData = data.filter(item => item.slice(-3) === "200");

console.log(filteredData);
```